# Change the text color when the mouse for all children div using css

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/suxedung/wH3nX/ [1]
I want all the hover text is white but it did not work!
This is my html code:

```
<div class="group_title">
    <a href="/be-positive-1">Be positive</a>    
    And you’ll acomplish everything
</div>
```

This is css code:

```
.group_title {
width:220px;
height:55px;
text-align:center;
font-size:11px;
color:#999999;
background: #f6f6f6;

}
.group_title a{
    display:block;
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;
    color: #444444;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;


.group_title:hover {
    width:220px;
    height:55px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:11px;
    background: #23abf1;
    cursor: pointer;    
}
 .group_title a:hover{   
    display:block;
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Please include the actual code in the question, not just in a link.

Comment: Your JSFiddle does not work, the link does not go to an existing page, please fix this or post your code so i can understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks for that annoying assumption, the problem sounds very simple to fix but i will not help now, no i'm not high btw i was directed to this 

Error 404
We're truly sorry, but there is no such page.

Comment: @Scotty4869 Just because you said that... Fix the problem and show me you can lol...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just answer it now.

So this is the `CSS` I added. When hovering on the `div` ALL the text will change to white. Using `.group_title:hover a` we can select that `a` and change its color when we hover over its parent.

### CSS:

```
.group_title:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:11px;
    background: #23abf1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.group_title:hover a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/wH3nX/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is malformed.

You are missing a closing bracket `}` for the `.group_title a {` section.

I have also updated your CSS in the following example to apply the desired effect: **http://jsfiddle.net/wH3nX/10/**

```
.group_title:hover,
.group_title:hover a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background: #23abf1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I have stripped out any erroneous changes and applied the effect to both the `<div/>` and `<a/>` elements.

Comment: @Ruddy answer updated. Now go update your question `;-)`

Comment: Much better, I posted mine just before you xD

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the css please check and update

http://jsfiddle.net/wH3nX/13/

```
a:hover   {color:red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.group_title a { ... }` is missing the closing bracket. That's because the next CSS sections doesn't work.